# pass data to a site from android

Tags: android

blahNow I am doing an ANdroid application.In my app I have to login using a url.Just like...www.blah.com/api/login/username/password.

```
private void sendAccelerationData()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","test3"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","pass3"));
    this.sendData(nameValuePairs);
}

private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new      
        HttpPost("http://blah.com/api/login/");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
}
```

but I am getting 404 error.and if i write my sendData() like

```
HttpPost("http://eesnap.com");
```

and sendAccelerationData() like

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","api"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","login"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","test3"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("","pass3"));
```

I am getting 200 success.
If post www.blah.com/api/login/username/password on brower then I am getting a result on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my error.In 'Get()' method i can write code like above but in post method I have to use name value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
HttpPost("http://www.blah.com/api/login/");
```

Comment: http://eesnap.com/api/login/test3/pass3.Copy this url on addressbar....can u check